# How to enable structural navigation for the quick launch navigation in CSOM?

Tags: csom, navigation, current-navigation

I create programmatically in CSOM/PNP a new subsite. This subsite do not needs to enhirit the quick launch navigation of the parent. I would like to set the navigation to structural navigation. And do not want to show subsites and pages. How to do that?

I did it already in powershell but cannot convert it to CSOM. Here is the powershell code:

```
    $web = get-spweb 'http://mycompany.com'

    # enable structural navigation for the global/quick launch navigation
    $navSetting = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings($web)
    $navSetting.CurrentNavigation.Source=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.StandardNavigationSource]::PortalProvider
    $navSetting.Update()

    # disable including pages/subsites for the quick launch navigation
    $SPPubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludeSubSites = $false
    $SPPubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludePages = $false
    $SPPubWeb.Update()

    $web.Dispose()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution with less code which I think it is the best. It is using CSOM Office Dev PnP:

```
AreaNavigationEntity nav = new AreaNavigationEntity();
nav.CurrentNavigation.ShowSubsites = false;
nav.CurrentNavigation.ShowPages = false;
web.UpdateNavigationSettings(nav);
```

Answer (score 4):

For enabling structural navigation you can use the code below:

```
var taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
var settings = new WebNavigationSettings(clientContext, web);

settings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;
settings.Update(taxonomySession);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

For other settings consider using this excellent [helper class](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7090347) by Vadim Gremyachev:

```
var navigation = new ClientPortalNavigation(ctx.Web);
navigation.CurrentIncludeSubSites = false;
navigation.CurrentIncludePages = false;
navigation.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

I found also this solution, it is almost the same as the solution of Kai just without the extra ClientPortalNavigation.cs file:

```
                // enable structural navigation for the quick launch navigation
                TaxonomySession taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(newWeb.Context);
                newWeb.Context.Load(taxonomySession);
                newWeb.Context.ExecuteQuery();

                WebNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(newWeb.Context, newWeb);
                navigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;
                navigationSettings.Update(taxonomySession);
                newWeb.Context.Load(navigationSettings);
                newWeb.Context.ExecuteQuery();

                // disable quick launch navigation including subsites
                string IncludeSubsitesKey = "__IncludeSubSitesInNavigation";
                if (newWeb.GetPropertyBagValueString(IncludeSubsitesKey, string.Empty) != null)
                    newWeb.RemovePropertyBagValue(IncludeSubsitesKey);

                newWeb.SetPropertyBagValue(IncludeSubsitesKey, bool.FalseString);
```